# Run a command in the context of a different app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, system-calls

I have two rails apps on the same server, let's call them A and B.

I am trying to have app A restart app B via app B's own capistrano task. Unfortunately, even after cd-ing to app B's directory, it is trying to run app A's capistrano instead. Am I missing something?

example code

`system("cd /apps/appB/current && pwd && bundle exec cap:restart")`

pwd correctly returns the path of appB (/apps/appB/current), however, in there is a traceback for cap:restart. This is because it is still trying to run the cap command in the context of appA, e.g.

`/apps/appA/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in 'require': cannot load such file -- airbrake/capistrano (LoadError)
from /apps/appA/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in 'require'.`

I tried without 'bundle exec', and have tried some other ways of making system calls. I also created a bash script in another directory and tried to run it that way.

All methods described exhibit the same behaviour.

Your help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: In appb have you done bundle install for capistrano

Comment: yeah I have done that

Comment: in appB Gemfile has capistrano?

Comment: What app server are you using?  If you're using Unicorn you could restart by sending a signal directly to the other app, without needing to use capistrano.

Comment: @bratsche I'm using unicorn with foreman, I might just have to do it with foreman, thanks. I am still hoping to find a way to do it via rails as I want to look into using appA as a complete control centre for the other apps and would like to extend it at some point down the track to deploy as well.

Comment: are you a root user? As your directory save in where in root? as you mentioned it is in /app it means it is in root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Bundler.with_clean_env` to ensure that your subprocess doesn't pick up your current Bundler environment:

```rb
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  system("cd /apps/appB/current && pwd && bundle exec cap:restart")
end
```

This is essentially the same problem as [Install bundle of gem within other rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983508/install-bundle-of-gem-within-other-rails-application)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your apps are using Unicorn, you can signal from app A to app B (or the other way around).

Read this page: http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html

The only thing each application needs to know is the pidfile path of the other application.  So look at your Unicorn config and see where it's storing that.

You could either read the PID out of that pidfile and kill it from Ruby:

```
pid = File.read(path_to_other_application_pidfile).chop
Process.kill("USR2", pid)
```

Or you could use backticks to execute shell commands

```
`kill -s USR2 \`cat #{path_to_other_application_pidfile}\``
```